# Viewing http over ports other than 80 or 443

Tags: http, localhost, port, jupyter-notebook, ssh-tunnel

I'm using jupyter notebooks on a remote server. I can start the notebook on a particular port such as 8000. I would have thought I would be able to see the notebook at `server:8000`, but I get a "can't connect" error.

However, if I start an ssh tunnel `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 server`, then I can see the notebook at `localhost:8000`.

So why can't I use the url and port? What kind of setting would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like "server" is behind a firewall that is not allowing incoming traffic on port 8000. SSH traffic (port 22) is likely allowed, so that is why you're having to tunnel in.  I think it's more of a networking question than a `jupyter-notebook` question.

Comment: You are correct--it is behind a firewall. I think I understand. I forgot that just because a server is speaking on a port doesn't mean it is listening on a port. So I either need to use the tunnel, ask the sysadmins to open some other ports, or proxy those ports to suburls.